# Return aggregated JSON from BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

If I have the below `example_table` in BigQuery. When I query the table with "Original Query" I get the "Actual Result" (which makes since). Is there a way to query BigQuery directly to get the "Desired Result"

### Original Query

```
SELECT ID, SUBID FROM `example_table ORDER BY ID
```

### example_table

```
ID | SUBID
12   abc
12   def
12   ghi
34   jkl
34   mno
56   prg
```

### Actual Result

```
[{
    "ID": "12",
    "SUBID": "abc"
}, {
    "ID": "12",
    "SUBID": "def"
}, {
    "ID": "12",
    "SUBID": "ghi"
}, {
    "ID": "34",
    "SUBID": "jkl"
}, {
    "ID": "34",
    "SUBID": "mno"
}, {
        "ID": "56",
        "SUBID": "prg"
    }]
```

### Desired Result

```
[{
    "ID": "12",
    "SUBID": ["abc", "def", "ghi"]
}, {
    "ID": "34",
    "SUBID": ["jkl", "mno"]
}, {
        "ID": "56",
        "SUBID": ["prg"]
    }]
```

Comment: why you have mysql tag?

Comment: It is my understanding that BigQuery implements MySQL syntax for its queries. I removed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT ID, ARRAY_AGG(SUBID) SUBID
FROM `project.dataset.example_table`
GROUP BY ID
```

You can test, play with above using sample data from your question as in example below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.example_table` AS (
  SELECT 12 ID, 'abc' SUBID UNION ALL
  SELECT 12, 'def' UNION ALL
  SELECT 12, 'ghi' UNION ALL
  SELECT 34, 'jkl' UNION ALL
  SELECT 34, 'mno' UNION ALL
  SELECT 56, 'prg' 
)
SELECT ID, ARRAY_AGG(SUBID) SUBID
FROM `project.dataset.example_table`
GROUP BY ID
-- ORDER BY ID
```

with result

[image]

Comment: Thanks! this is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

If BigQuery does use MySQL syntax you might be able to do this. If not you can continue CONCAT throughout all of your query using multiple selects but it would be a little more convoluted instead of the JSON_ARRAYAGG.

```
SELECT CONCAT('{','ID:', ID,', SUBID:', JSON_ARRAYAGG(SUBID),'}') as JSON
FROM contact GROUP BY ID;
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/37ru5oq4dFQSscwYsfx386/25

Comment: This is what i was looking for so i really appreciate it. However, I guess BigQuery isn't a full implementation of MySQL. I get a `Function not found: JSON_ARRAYAGG` error. I was able to parse out the data and build the json on my server. Thanks